# Merging audio file is very slow android java

Tags: java, android, audio, merge, mp4parser

I'm merging audio file using mp4parser. Merging is done but it is very slow don't know what is the issue.

On this line debugger stuck for big audio files

***Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);***

Here is my working but slow performance code.

```
public static void mergAudio(List<File> filesToMearge){


try {
    while (filesToMearge.size()!=1) {

        String audio1 = filesToMearge.get(0).getPath();
        String audio2 = filesToMearge.get(1).getPath();


        // FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(filesToMearge.get(0).getPath(),true);//destinationfile
        String outputVideo = filesToMearge.get(0).getPath();

        Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[]{
                MovieCreator.build(audio1),
                MovieCreator.build(audio2),
        };

        List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

        for (Movie m : inMovies) {
            for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                    audioTracks.add(t);
                }
            }
        }


        Movie result = new Movie();

        if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
            result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
        }

        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
        out.writeContainer(new FileOutputStream(outputVideo).getChannel());

    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

How can i improve the performance any idea Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Nisar have you got any solution?

Comment: Hi @Bhumit no did not get any good solution for this.